# Removing child entity from parent entity - EF Core 2.2

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I would like to remove an item from collection which exist in one entity. The problem I face is:

> -entity is being removed from context
>
> -after save changes the entity still exists

The Parent object:

```
public class MyObject
{
    public int Id { get; private set; }
    public ICollection<ChildObject> ChildObjcets { get; private set; }

    public void RemoveChildObject(ChildObject @object)
    {
        this.ChildObjcets.Remove(@object);
    }
}
```

the Child object:

```
 public class ChildObject
 {
    public int Id { get; private set; }

    public MyObject MyObject { get; set; }
    public int MyObjectId { get; set; }
}
```

What I have tried:

```
public void Proceed()
{
     //myObject contain 4 child objects inside
     var myObject = _repo.GetMyObject();
     var childObject = _repo.GetChildObject();

     myObject.RemoveChildObject(childObject);
    //myObject contain 3 items now
```

}

Before saving the changes I do not see removed entity in the change tracker - the state should be Removed?

```
var childObjects = ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(x => x.Entity is ChildObject).ToList(); // returns 3 - the removed one does not exist
```

However when I save changes then the root object still contain 4 entities - so the child object was not removed at all

```
_repo.SaveChanges();       
var myObject = _repo.GetMyObject();
```

Any idea how to handle removing child object from root entity?

Comment: The state of the child entity in the change tracker should be Modified. And after `SaveChanges` the child entity should be deleted in database and the change tracker entry should disappear. All that *only* if cascade delete is on, are you sure you didn't turn it off with fluent API?

Comment: Your code works flawlessly for me. The behavior is exactly what @IvanStoev describes .

Answer (score 1):

In Entity Framework 6 a faster way to do the operation is

```
context.Children.RemoveRange(parent.Children)
```

Answer (score 0):

Removing the `ChildObject` from `ChildObjcets` (also, note the typo) collection means removing the relation rather than removing the entity from `DbContext`. To completely remove the entity you need to explicitly call `Remove` on the `DbSet<ChildObject>` which you cannot do directly from your root object.

I suggest moving this operation to your `_repo` whatever it actually references to. It should have access to `DbContext` hence any `DbSet<>`.

Comment: if it removed just relation why cant I get all 4 childojbects from context before save changes?